# Unable to query by Timestamp in CosmosDB with Table API

Tags: .net-core, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I'm creating a query to include Cosmos entities from the last 30 days:

```
var filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate(
                "Timestamp", 
                QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual,
                DateTimeOffset.Now.Date.AddDays(-30));
```

Next I create a query using this filter:

```
var query = new TableQuery<ResponseEntity>().Where(filter);
```

Next I execute the query:

```
var result = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);
```

However, for some reason, the `result` always contains zero (0) hits.

If I execute the query without any filter...

```
var query = new TableQuery<ResponseEntity>();
```

...I do get all entities.

Looking at the generated filter string, it looks OK to me (and identical to the one in the Azure portal when using the query builder for Cosmos):

`Timestamp ge datetime'2018-09-15T22:00:00.0000000Z'`

Is there any limitation on querying based on `Timestamp`?

**Edit:** Tried switching to the new `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` NuGet package (currently in preview, version **0.9.1**), but I'm still not getting any results when filtering by `Timestamp`.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: @JayGong I haven't had a chance to try it, but I couldn't immediately see any major differences? Are you also targeting .NET Core? Which versions of the Azure storage NuGet packages are you using?

Comment: Ted,never mind, waiting for your test. My sample code just ran in the .net console test app and the nuget packages I installed is Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common 9.0.0.1-preview and Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to my working code.

***code:***

```
using Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JayGongCosmosTable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TableQuerySegment <ResponseEntity>  resultE=  QueryTableAsync("test").Result;
            foreach(ResponseEntity re in resultE)
            {                    
                Console.WriteLine("Timestamp:   "+re.Timestamp);
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("execute done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async Task<TableQuerySegment<ResponseEntity>> QueryTableAsync(string tableName)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString("***");
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);

            var filter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate(
                "Timestamp",
                QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual,
                //QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual,
                DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-10).Date);

            Console.WriteLine(filter);

            var query = new TableQuery<ResponseEntity>().Where(filter);

            var result = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);

            return result;

        }
    }


    class ResponseEntity : TableEntity
    {    
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset logtime { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My data list as below without filter:

[image]

If I used Timestamp as filter, it works:

[image]

Another thing I'd like to mention is, please avoid `timestamp` interval query if possible. Such a query will result in a whole table scan in server side. If `timestamp` interval query is needed usually in your scenario, please consider choosing `timestamp` as your partition key or row key to optimize the query performance.

---

Just for summary, finally , the solution is `uninstalling WindowsAzure.Storage` and switch using statements to use types from `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table` instead.

Comment: This is pretty much the same thing I did, and it doesn't work. I'm using `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core` **2.1.3** and `WindowsAzure.Storage` **9.3.2**.

Comment: @TedNyberg No,No, please use `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table`. I used `WindowsAzure.Storage` previously and failed, success with `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table`

Comment: The `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table` package doesn't seem to be available for .NET Core. :/

Comment: Also tried the preview of the `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` package, but that didn't work either.

Comment: @TedNyberg Strangely,I tested successfully in a pure .net framework console app. And my package is `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table 2.0.0` and  `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common 9.0.0.1-preview`.

Comment: @TedNyberg Let's chat in this room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182397/for-cosmos-table

Comment: @TedNyberg I'll test `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table 0.9.1-preview` for .net core console app and share the result here.

Comment: Please post that as an answer (uninstalling `WindowsAzure.Storage` and switch `using` stamements to use types from `Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table` instead). I've closed the GitHub issue. :)

Comment: @TedNyberg Yeah! I already summarized the solution in my answer.